# Falha ao remover elemento array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou criando uma página que irá filtrar algumas sugestões, onde o usuário pode votar nas quais forem mais interessantes para ele.

Estou dividindo esta tela em 3 abas [Mais Votados], [Mais Novas] e [Meus Votos]
Ao iniciar a tela eu faço uma chamada no banco de dados que traz todas as sugestões, faço isso através do `axios`

```
axios
      .get("/sugestoes/carregar/xxxx")
      .then(res => {
        this.sugestoesGeral = res.data.sugestoes

        for(var i=0; i < this.sugestoesGeral.length; i++){
          if(this.sugestoesGeral[i].meu_voto === "S"){
            this.meusVotos.splice(1, 0, this.sugestoesGeral[i])
          }
        }

        this.maisVotados     = [...this.sugestoesGeral]
        this.maisNovos       = [...this.sugestoesGeral] 
        this.ordernarArrVotos(this.maisVotados)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Desta forma inicio meus três arrays diferentes a partir da primeira chamada na base de dados

Quando o usuário Votar em alguma sugestão faço ele reordenar os arrays de acordo com a sua respectiva aba [Mais Votados], [Mais Novas] e [Meus Votos]

Os arrays `this.maisVotados` e `this.maisNovos` são reordenados sem nenhum problema. Porém o array `this.meusVotos` eu preciso executar outras ações além de simplesmente reordenar, preciso verificar se ele removeu um voto, caso tenho feito isso preciso remover essa posição do array e então mostrar novamente ao usuário

Para remover uma posição do array estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.sugestoesGeral.length; i++){
        if(this.sugestoesGeral[i].meu_voto === 'N'){
          var length = this.meusVotos.length
          for(var x=0; x < length; x++){
            if(this.meusVotos[x].id_sugestao === this.sugestoesGeral[i].id_sugestao){
              this.meusVotos.splice(x, 1)
            }
          }
        }
      }

console.log(this.meusVotos)
```

Porém desta forma ele não surte nenhum efeito e não remove nenhuma posição do meu array. Apenas para teste fiz da seguinte forma:

```
this.meusVotos.shift()
console.log(this.meusVotos)
```

Porém o resultado é o mesmo, nenhum elemento é removido do meu array. O mais curioso é que fiz uma cópia destes arrays para testar no console do navegador e ele funciona sem erros. segue exemplo somente para jogarem no console e ver que funciona

Arrays:

```
sugestoesGeral = [
                    {
                        status_atual: "Em votação",
                        categoria: "Parâmetros",
                        quantidade_votos: 1,
                        meu_voto: "S",
                        id_sugestao: 16,
                        titulo: "Alerta de Valor Excedente por Cliente no MDF-e",
                        data_criacao: "29/01/2020",
                        descricao_resumida: "Alerta de Valor Excedente por Cliente no MDF-e",
                        motivo_rejeicao: "",
                        data_rejeicao: "",
                        data_implementacao: "",
                        data_previsao_execucao: "",
                        data_encerramento_votacao: "",
                        cor: "#b8dbff"
                    },
                    {
                        status_atual: "Em votação",
                        categoria: "Despesas",
                        quantidade_votos: 1,
                        meu_voto: "N",
                        id_sugestao: 7,
                        titulo: "Nova coluna Controle de Despesas",
                        data_criacao: "28/01/2020",
                        descricao_resumida: "Checar vínculo financeiro da Despesa quando vinculada a uma Nota com Financeiro lançado",
                        motivo_rejeicao: "",
                        data_rejeicao: "",
                        data_implementacao: "",
                        data_previsao_execucao: "",
                        data_encerramento_votacao: "",
                        cor: "#b8dbff"
                    }
                ]

meusVotos = [
                    {
                        status_atual: "Em votação",
                        categoria: "Parâmetros",
                        quantidade_votos: 1,
                        meu_voto: "S",
                        id_sugestao: 16,
                        titulo: "Alerta de Valor Excedente por Cliente no MDF-e",
                        data_criacao: "29/01/2020",
                        descricao_resumida: "Alerta de Valor Excedente por Cliente no MDF-e",
                        motivo_rejeicao: "",
                        data_rejeicao: "",
                        data_implementacao: "",
                        data_previsao_execucao: "",
                        data_encerramento_votacao: "",
                        cor: "#b8dbff"
                    },
                    {
                        status_atual: "Em votação",
                        categoria: "Despesas",
                        quantidade_votos: 1,
                        meu_voto: "N",
                        id_sugestao: 7,
                        titulo: "Nova coluna Controle de Despesas",
                        data_criacao: "28/01/2020",
                        descricao_resumida: "Checar vínculo financeiro da Despesa quando vinculada a uma Nota com Financeiro lançado",
                        motivo_rejeicao: "",
                        data_rejeicao: "",
                        data_implementacao: "",
                        data_previsao_execucao: "",
                        data_encerramento_votacao: "",
                        cor: "#b8dbff"
                    }
                ]
```

For para efetuar a remoção do elemento:

```
 for(var i=0; i < this.sugestoesGeral.length; i++){
        if(this.sugestoesGeral[i].meu_voto === 'N'){
          var length = this.meusVotos.length
          for(var x=0; x < length; x++){
            if(this.meusVotos[x].id_sugestao === this.sugestoesGeral[i].id_sugestao){
              this.meusVotos.splice(x, 1)
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vinda

Comment: Coloca um `console.log("ok");` dentro do `if` onde tem a linha `this.meusVotos.splice(x, 1)` para ver se está entrando nele.

Comment: Sim @Sam quando eu removo um voto e clico para chamar esse método ele passar pelo ```console.log('OK')```

Comment: @Sam tem alguma outra sugestão do que poderia tentar, já efetuei algumas mudanças com o filter() porém também sem sucesso

Comment: Cara, em vez do splice, tenta fazer um push pra ver se algo é adicionado na array. É só comentar a linha `this.meusVotos.splice(x, 1)` e colocar abaixo dela um `this.meusVotos.push("x")`... veja se o último item da array aparece o `"x"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `array.filter()` para trazer apenas as sugestões com `meu_voto === 'S'`:

```
this.meusVotos = this.sugestoesGeral.filter(sugestao => sugestao.meu_voto === 'S')
```

[Documentação do array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Comment: eu testei com a sua resposta e o realmente a opção foi removida do array, muito obrigado!